# import module inside the module in python

Tags: python, import, package

Python 3.10

I have a project structure like so:

```
./main.py  
models/__init__.py  
models/file1.py  
models/file2.py 
models/file3.py
```

main.py:

```
from models import file1, file2, file3
```

models/file1.py:

```
from models import file2
```

models/file2.py:

```
from models import file3
```

when I execute main.py, so far so good. But the fact is that I would like to execute file1.py as a standalone script as well like:

```
python file1.py
```

but now, python cannot find the models package since it is in it!
My work around is to append ./models in sys.path from main.py and just:

```
import file2
```

in file1.py, but it is not really satisfying, I would like to continue importing file2 with the statement

```
from models import file2
```

since it seems more pythonic and more 'portable'.

How to do so?

Comment: Use absolute path (`import models.file2` instead of `from models import file2`)

Comment: if I execute file1 with import models.file2 in it, it raises a ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'models.file2', models is not a package

Comment: `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../"))` before import?

Comment: as depicted, I am not satisfied with the sys.path.append thing, I thought python was able to figure out that the executed file is inside a module that we can use.